# Make HashMap Type Key-Value pair in PHP

Tags: php, hashmap, key-value

I have two arraylist and i have converted them into HashMap like below

```
ArrayList<Integer> productIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> productQuantity = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Map<Integer, Integer> saleReport = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

for(int i=0;i<productIds.size();i++){
      saleReport.put(productIds.get(i), productQuantity.get(i));
}
```

**Now i want to do the same thing in PHP. I want to convert two array's into the HashMap's like KeyValue Pair.**

I have these two arrays in PHP with the equal number of items. Please guide me how can i do that.

Comment: $saleReport[ $productIds[$i] ] = $productQuantity[$i];

Comment: PHP is not a strongly typed language like Java. In PHP you can simply use arrays.

Answer (score 2):

It's as simple as:

```
$productIds = array( /** Your data */ );
$productQuantity  = array( /** Your data */ );

$n = count($productIds);
$saleReport = array();
for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++) {
  $saleReport[$productIds[$i]] = $productQuantity[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$productIds = array();
$productQuantity = array();
$saleReport = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($productIds); $i++) {
    $saleReport[$productIds[$i]] = $productQuantity[$i];
}
```

In PHP arrays can have string keys.